# Compare two excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I would like to compare 2 dictionary that retrieve the data from an excel file and I would like for each user to compare his number of absence in between the 2 dictionary and return a message with the name of the user for whom the number of absence will not be equal in the 2 dictionary.

```
{"jazi": 1, "juge": 1, "juha": 9, "lebe": 4}
{"jazi": 3, "juge": 7, "juha": 5, "lebe": 4}
```

Like this and the function should return for this example :"" "jazi" not equal ""

I show you my code :

```
                for row in range(1,253):
                  id2.append(feuille_2.cell_value(row, 2))
                  absence2.append(float(feuille_2.cell_value(row, 9)))

                result = {}
                for name in set(id2):
                    result[name] = 0


                for i in range(len(id2)):
                   hours = float(absence2[i])
                   name = id2[i]
                   result[name] += hours

                print(result)
```

and the other :

```
                for row in range(1,360):
                  id.append(feuille_1.cell_value(row, 2))
                  absence2.append(float(feuille_1.cell_value(row, 9)))

                result2 = {}
                for name2 in set(id):
                    result[name2] = 0


                for i in range(len(id)):
                   hours2 = float(absence[i])
                   name2 = id[i]
                   result[name2] += hours2

                print(result2)
```

I just have one more question if in one of my dictionary i have more value than the other can i still compare both dictionary or i have to change my code ?
Like this :

```
dict1={"jazi": 1, "juge": 1, "juha": 9, "lebe": 4}
dict2={"jazi": 3, "juge": 4, "juha": 1, "lebe": 4, "aba":7, "meze":9}
```

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
dict1={"jazi": 1, "juge": 1, "juha": 9, "lebe": 4}
dict2={"jazi": 3, "juge": 7, "juha": 5, "lebe": 4}
for key in dict1:
    if dict1[key]!=dict2[key]:
        print("%s not equal"% (key))
```

output:

```
jazi not equal
juge not equal
juha not equal
```

I hope to understand your question

Comment: Yes you understand the question but does it work if the index do not match between the 2 dictionary for example like this :                                                                                             dict1={"juge": 1, "jazi": 1, "lebe": 9, "juha": 4}
dict2={"jazi": 3, "juge": 7, "juha": 5, "lebe": 4}